# Public interface for nearest neighbor data structures

Tags: c++, c++11, interface

I am making a small library of **metric data structures**. That is data structures, which associate points in the n-dimensional space with objects and allow the user to find objects which are **closest to a certain query** with respect to a metric.

I have already implemented several data structures such as **K-d trees, M-trees** and **R-trees**, but they all have different interfaces. I am trying to factor out some common elements and make a common base interface for these data structures.

I am a beginner programmer and after I refactor my code I want to publish it for the first time in my life, hopefully for other users to use it. Therefore I would be grateful for any comments which can make the interface:

1. more intuitive
2. in line with best practices
3. less likely to change in the future (since other people may be using it by then)
4. taking advantage of C++11 (such as move semantics)

At the beginning there is a `NearestNeighbors::Queue` class which symbolizes a result of a search for `k` nearest neighbors. I use a separate class for this purpose, since in the future I may want to play with the implementation a little, since this is a performance critical part of the code. Currently it is implemented as a `std::prioity_queue`.

```
using Real = double;

namespace NearestNeighbors
{
template <class TPayload>
class Queue
{
public:
    Queue(std::size_t maxSize);

    typedef std::pair<Real, TPayload> Pair;
    Pair popMostDistant();

    Real highestDistance() const;
    std::size_t size() const;
private: 
    ...
};
}
```

The following template class serves as a base class to all my **metric data structures**.

```
namespace NearestNeighbors
{
template <typename TPayload, typename TVector = std::vector<Real>>
class Structure
{
public: 

    template <typename TIterator,
              typename TGetPosition,
              typename TGetPayload>
    Structure(TIterator begin,
              TIterator end,
              TGetPosition getPosition,
              TGetPayload getPayload);

    // Batch is used to store all payloads at a specific position.
    using Batch = std::list<TPayload>;

    const Batch& operator[] (const TVector& position) const;

    bool contains (const TVector& position, const TPayload& query) const;

    void insert   (const TVector& position, const TPayload& toInsert);
    void insert   (const TVector& position, const Batch& toInsert);
    // Maybe add interface to move-insert elements

    bool remove   (const TVector& position, const TPayload& toRemove);
    bool remove   (const TVector& position, const Batch& toRemove);
    bool remove   (const TVector& position);

    std::size_t computeSize() const;

    using Metric = Real (*)(const TVector&, const TVector&);         

    template <Metric metric = euclideanMetric>
    TPayload findFirstExactNearest(const TVector& position) const;

    template <Metric metric = euclideanMetric>
    const Batch& findExactNearest(const TVector& position) const;

    template <Metric metric = euclideanMetric>
    NearestNeighbors::Queue<TPayload> findExactKNN (const TVector& query,
                                                    std::size_t k) const;

    // The same interface for "findApproximateNearest"

private: 
    ...

};
} // namespace NearestNeighbors
```

An example of the usage could be a geographic system that looks up restaurants which are close to the user.

```
struct Restaurant
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Real> location;
};


int main()
{
    ...
    std::vector<Restaurant> restaurants = generateRestaurants();
    auto getPayload = [](const Restaurant& r)  {return r;};
    auto getPosition = [](const Restaurant& r) {return r.location;};
    NearestNeighbors::Structure<Restaurant> restaurantLookup(restaurants.begin(),
                                                             restaurants.end(),
                                                             getPosition,
                                                             getPayload);
    std::vector<Real> myposition = getMyPosition();
    /// I want to go to the nearest restaurant.
    Restaurant nearest = restaurantLookup.findFirstExactNearest(myposition);
    std::cout << "I am going to " << nearest.name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example how to use this in a useful way? I do not see the problem your code solves. It is not immediately obvious why I want to use your `Queue` instead of an `std::queue` or an `std::vector`, what `Structure` is for and why you don't just have a free function to find nearest neighbors in a more general way.

Comment: I would like to see some reasoning. E.g. why `Queue` and not `std::queue` or `std::priority_queue`. Why `Batch` and not two iterators (`It from, It to`).

Comment: @nwp I am sorry for the confusion. I edited my question to answer your questions as much as I could. The purpose of metric structures is to find nearest neighbors in logarithmic, instead of linear time. For this purpose, the data needs to be in a tree-like data structure, hence the use of a class and not just free functions. Since there are many approaches how to implement this metric data structure (K-d trees, M-trees, ...)  I want to make a unified interface, which would capture the nearest-neighbor-y essence of these data structures.

Comment: @firda I edited my question to provide reasoning for `Queue`. As far as `Batch` is concerned, it is supposed to store all the payload associated to one node. Why did I use `Batch` instead of a pair of iterators? That is a good question. It just never came to my mind. What is the advantage of returning a pair of iterators?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: I was a bit confused what `Batch` really is... attributes e.g. like distance, travel speed, ...? Two iterators are usually used as arguments to e.g. remove-range.

Comment: @firda I am sorry, but I do not understand what do you mean by attributes.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: then what is payload? I think I missunderstood it here, mixed edges with nodes (this is no graph / dijkstra, but map - nodes/points only).

Comment: @firda I edited my question to add an example. There are no edges and all the internals should be hidden. Yes, it is similar to a `std::map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First scan

`using Real = double` - not bad, but I would use another template parameter (defaulted to `double`).

`Queue` - now we know it is actually `std::priority_queue` (which is **heap**).

- Why removing from highest (not least) distance?
- Why `Pair` from pop, but `Real` from peek?
- Why heap at all? It could be constructed as a heap, but it is rather used as a set/vector/deque once it is returned. Maybe `Matches` would be better name for it (you should **describe the purpose**, not the internal structure), but I am no expert to know what is the real purpose and what algorithms can be used.

`TPayload` vs. `Batch` - the later seems to allow multiple *nodes* (e.g. cities or what payload can be) in same place + accept/return list of such nodes/elements. What I am really missing is some [Doxygen](http://doxygen.org) documentation describing every method and adding some usage example *(**note:** the example was edited in the question while I was writing this review)*.

`void insert   (const TVector& position, const Batch& toInsert);` - I would personally add another method taking pair of iterators:

```
template<class It> void insert(const TVector& position, It from, It to) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<TPayload,std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>::value, ...);
```

`std::size_t computeSize() const;` - what is that method doing? Number of vectors? Something different?

### The names and design

The `Structure` looks like `std::(multi)map`, where `TVector` is something like location/position (seen in example) - a key - and `TPayload` is the value. Why not naming it that way? As already mentioned, `TVector` may describe what is it about, but still is too connected with the implementation, not the purpose. (The location could be enumeration and our metric could measure the distance using dijkstra or whatever algorithm.)

`findFirstExactNearest` vs. `findExactNearest` + `Batch`: I would take inspiration in [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) and use pair of iterators - there would be no need for `Batch` and the two methods could be made one.

`ExactNearest` vs. `ApproximateNearest`: which of the two will be most used? What about adding another template parameter (`bool` or `enum (class)`) for it? The name could then be simply `nearest` (`find` can be removed as well).